# Debugging Actionmailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, email-client

I have actionmailer set up. Emails are not being sent, and no errors.

Where can I start my search to debug this?

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base

default_url_options[:host] = APP_DOMAIN

def email_blast(user, subject, message)
subject subject
from NOTIFIER_EMAIL
recipients user.email
sent_on Time.zone.now
body :user => user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name, :message => message
end
```

I do get a return in my log that the email was sent, just no actual email goes through.

Also the reason, that this is not working is because I switched form a cluster to a solo box and some server settings were overwritten. I suspect that is probably the reason why this is not working. Anyone know what specific server settings I would have to look at ?

UPDATE:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "75.101.153.93" }
```

I found this in my production.rb . This code was originally here when it worked. Again, I believe that there must be something missing on my server..I did a 'which sendmail' and it returned /usr/bin/sendmail , so I added this :

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
 :location        => '/usr/bin/sendmail',
 :arguments       => '-i -t'
}
```

Redeployed, restarted the server, and tested it. No emails were sent.

The production.log said something was sent :

```
Processing MediaController#create_a_video (for 173.161.167.41 at 2010-06-03 11:58:13) [GET]
  Parameters: {"action"=>"create_a_video", "controller"=>"media", "organization_id"=>"470",     "_"=>"1275591493194"}
Sent mail to info@hqchannel.com
Rendering media/create_a_video
Completed in 128ms (View: 51, DB: 1) | 200 OK [http://invent.hqchannel.com/organizations/470/media/create_a_video?_=1275591493194]
```

Comment: More details please. Are you hosting with a webhost provider, running your own machine, have a VM, or what exactly?

Comment: Are you sure there's still something like sendmail, postfix or another mail server running on your machine?

Comment: Its sendmail . But its missing something still.

Comment: Does sendmail or your other system logs show anything?

Comment: @Matt S, do you know where that log hides usually? the sendmail command is in my usr/bin and usr/sbin, but no logs are in there and there are no logs of it where there usually is in my log/

Comment: sendmail should log to /var/log/syslog unless you've configured it differently.